# Correct usage of Bluebird promise

Tags: javascript, performance, node.js

This is related to [this question on promise performance](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/278778/why-are-native-es6-promises-slower-and-more-memory-intensive-than-bluebird). The current top answer states that using `new Promise` is

> an anti-pattern in bluebird

And that `promisify` should be used instead. I understand that `promisify`can be used for functions that are using callbacks. But if I have my own code that I want to get a promise from how should this be done?

For example at the moment I have a function that performs a rest call and I use:

```
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    ...
    resolve(data);
    ...
    reject(err);
}
```

I can then use this with the normal `.then()`. So this is correct for ES6, but if performing it the way bluebird intends what is the correct implementation to be as efficient as possible? As I think that taking my code and changing it to be handled with callbacks simply to use `promisify` seems a bit nuts.  Potentially I may have got the wrong end of the stick.

Answer (score 2):

This question probably doesn't belong to programmers but

```
var request = function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      ...
      resolve(data);
      ...
      reject(err);
    }
};
```

Is of course much slower than

```
var request = promisify(function(callback) {
    ...
    callback(null, data);
    ...
    callback(err);
});
```

However, this isn't the anti-pattern. The anti-pattern is using `new Promise` when `promisify` or `.then()` would suffice. For instance, here request is most likely just using some other APIs that already are implemented as callbacks/promises. Then `new Promise` is an anti-pattern because you should just chain the existing promise or promisify the callback api and then chain from the promises returned.

Comment: Considering the popularity of Bluebird, a brief explanation of this can be added to the documentation. What do you think?

Comment: So for clarity it isn't the use of `return new Promise` that is the anti pattern, it is when you already have a promise/thenable object or a callback that can be promisified: which means you're wrapping a promise in a promise.